increment a column and line number value using bash
I have a tab-delimited file that contains 4 columns
numbers.txt
0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0

In bash I need to be able to increment a specific column and line by 1, so for example +1 to column 2 line 3 to make it
0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0
0       1       0       0
0       0       0       0

I can get a specific column and line using
cat test | awk '{print $2}' | sed '3!d;q'

which returns 1 as expected but I can't work out how to update the value in a specific column/line i.e.
cat test | awk '{print $2}' | sed '3!d;q' | +1 to the value in this column


Where are you adding something in your code? print $2 just outputs the second field, which means that your other columns are gone.

You never need to pipe sed or awk to sed or awk, and you don't need cat to open files - see https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award

Can you provide more examples? Do you only want to increase by 1 once?

This awk should work for you:
awk -v r=3 -v c=2 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} NR == r {++$c} 1' file

0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0


@Lurch: See 8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR

Here is a Ruby that allows passing multiple values in a JSON array and all the changes are made at once (if they can be, based on the CSV table size):
ruby -r csv -r JSON -e '
   opts={:col_sep=>"\t", :converters=>:all} 
   cng=JSON.load(ARGV[0])
   tbl=CSV.parse(File.open(ARGV[1]).read, **opts)
   cng.each{|(r,c),v| tbl[r][c]+=v if r.abs<tbl.length && c.abs<tbl[r].length }
   puts CSV.generate(**opts){|csv| tbl.each{|r| csv<<r } }
' '[ [[2,1],1], [[0,2],-3], [[-1,0],1.2] ]' file.tsv

Prints:
0   0   -3  0
0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
1.2 0   0   0

Keep in mind that Ruby arrays are 0 based so row 3, col 2 would be expressed as [2,1]. The reference [-1,0] means last row, first column; any negative index is counting backwards from the array end in Ruby.

This might work for you (GNU sed and shell):
r=3 c=2
sed -E $r'{s/[0-9]+/$((&+1))/'$c';s/.*/echo "&"/e}' file

Assign 3 to r and 2 to c for row 3, column 2.
Increment the second column of numbers by one for the third row only and echo the evaluated result.
